# Is there a way to find the integrated graphics for my processor?

Tags: cpu, integrated-graphics

For a computer (even with a GPU), is there a way to find out what kind of integrated graphics would be on my processor and a way to test the performance?

My Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3820 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 3801 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What kind of integrated graphics would be on my processor?

http://ark.intel.com/ is the source for information about Intel products.

[image]

Source [Intel® Core™ i7-3820QM Processor (8M Cache, up to 3.70 GHz)](http://ark.intel.com/products/64889/Intel-Core-i7-3820QM-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows on your machine, you can find information about graphics Chipset and integrated graphics card by running DirectX Diagnostic tools (dxdiag).

To run dxdiag, type `dxdiag` on Run prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

I can see following on my Samsung book 8, running Windows 10 and has Intel 4000 series graphics chipset and AMD Radeon graphics card.
[image]
[image]

Regarding testing performance of graphics chipset.
If you are running Windows prior to Windows 8.1, You can run a performance test using "Windows Experience Index" (Control Panel\System and Security\System).

Or you could get a software like 3DMark to do a Graphics Performance test.